# Percentage accuracy of a prediction

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements, error-analysis

Although it appears trivial, I am stuck at the following problem:

I am searching for a formula to express the (percentage) accuracy of a prediction about temperature. However, most methods I have found rather use errors to measure accuracy where a high error, means a model "bad" pediction and 0 error means a perfect prediction.

But is there a formula to express the accuracy in a way where a low value means low accuracy and the closer a value is to 100, the higher the accuracy?

If $A$ is the accuracy of the prediction (where $0⩽A⩽100)$, $T_M$ is the temperature I measured and $T_P$ is the temperature predicted by some formula, what is the "best" way to calculate the $A$, accuracy of the prediction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that usually, it is expressed such that the higher the accuracy, the smaller is the error bar. However, there are many ways to recalculate the corresponding value, and you are free to choose the one you find the best.

Essentially, you have a measure of inaccuracy as $|\Delta T/T_p|$, where $\Delta T = T_m - T_p$, and you just have to construct a mathematical function which would give $1$ at $\Delta T=0$ and $0$ at $|\Delta T|\rightarrow\infty$. One way to do it would be $\exp(-|\Delta T/T_p|)$, but as I said, there are many others.

Comment: This is what I have been looking for, I think $e^x$ will suffice as a function! Thanks a lot!